# References for how to build knowledge and representations from discourse

Tags: knowledge, knowledge-representation

First of all I would like to say that I am asking this for a friend and I have no previous knowledge of the field so the terminology that I am using might be erroneous. Feel free to leave comments asking for clarification in that case.

My friend is interested in bibliography about how we build knowledge and representation from discourse. She has been reading Foucault so far but she would like to read some more material to clarify what she has understood.

What texts could serve as suitable references in this subject?